# How to implement php code insert in hadoop hive

Tags: php, hadoop, hive

I want to read the two corpus into hive , like php code blow

```
<?php 
for (i=0;i<corpus1_size;i++){
  for(j=0;j<corpus2_size;j++){
   // execute the MySQL insert code : insert into table (copus1,corpus2)value(corpus1[i],corpus2[jj);
}
}
?>
```

Is any suggestion for me to implement php code to hive system ?

## read the data store into hadoop system ?

this two corpus data is over 1TB , I want to quick store the data.
suitable step ?

Comment: established the hadoop and install the hive

Comment: also store 2 corpus into hdfs